# Java Var-args and enhanced for loop compiler error

Tags: java, variadic-functions, foreach

Please explain why the following code snippet fails to compile:

```
public class ScjpTest{

static void go(int... i){
    System.out.println("In 1");

    for (int x : i){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

static void go(int i){
    System.out.println("In 2");

    for (int x : i){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    go(1);
    go(1,2);
    go(1,2,3);

}
}
```

I was testing to see which instance of go() will be called but it is failing with the following error:

```
ScjpTest.java:16: foreach not applicable to expression type
                  for (int x : i){
                         ^
1 error
```

I cant for the life of me work out what is wrong with the enhanced for loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first overload, `i` is an *array* of integers. That's how you can iterate over it. In the second overload, it's just a *single integer value*. The enhanced for loop only works over `Iterable` instances and arrays - not single values. You should just write:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

as there's bound to just be one value.

Comment: Oh i thought that the error was on the first go() method. Got confused because they used the same named. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

In the second `go()` method, you're trying to iterate over an int, not an array of ints (which is what the varargs break down to.) Since you can't meaningfully iterate over an int, the compiler complains.

Answer (score 3):

You can't iterate over a single integer. It worked for your method using `varargs` input because it's an array of integers, equivalent to an `int[]` argument.

You can simply use this:

```
static void go(int i){
    System.out.println("In 2");

    System.out.println(i);
}
```